# Last person to enter Jannah would he really have a Jannah?

Tags: allah, jannah

I was reading hadith about last person to enter Jannah where prophet Musa asked Allah Most High about it.  Allah Most Great said to the last person to enter Jannah and Allah said "Will you not be content if you could have the equivalent of a kingdom on earth?"

What I want to know would it be like planet earth for this person, like houses, wives, foods etc will be like they are in planet earth, same quality?.  Hadith says equivalent of a kingdom on earth?" does that mean he wouldn't taste real Jannah since his Jannah maybe like planet earth?  I hope I made sense and Allah Knows Best.

Answer (score 2):

As you yourself acknowledged, the hadith clearly says:

> Verily the Messenger of Allah said: **The last to enter Paradise** would be a man who would walk once and stumble once and be burnt by the Fire once.

Meaning that the person will indeed enter Paradise. There is no such thing as "real" paradise vs. fake paradise. Presumably, the reference to "earth" or "world" is a comparison to size, magnitude, or appearance.

Regarding appearance, it is well-known that Earth and the things on it imitate the things in Paradise. For example, with regards to fruits:

> [In Paradise] whenever they are provided with their fruit for nourishment, they will say, ‘This is what we were provided before,’ and they were [only] given something resembling it. (2:25)